# Postgresql replication in Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, database-replication

I've got a Rails 4 application ready to be deployed. However, I'd like to consider the possibility of doing it both in Europe and USA datacenters. The reason why is I'm expecting 50%-50% visitors from both places, and I'd like to give a really good service in both ends.

For many of the tables/models I could use a Master-Slave replication model, as I'm going to administer the content only from Europe, and changes could be pushed asyncronously to USA. However, for a few of the tables (user, and user-related content) I'd need some sort of Master-Master replication, as users can generate content from each side of the ocean, and they should be able to "see" the content generated by the others.

How can I approach this replication scenario? Would a custom primary key be a good option to avoid conflict? (Like: EUR-1, EUR-2, USA-1, USA-2).

I've got no experience with Postgres replication whatsoever, an easy to mantain solution would be fine, even if I had to sacrifice immediate syncing (at least for user related data, I suppose the Master-Slave tables can be easily pushed)

Thank you!

Comment: Given the speed and latency between Europe/US I'd suggest this is not a problem. Have you done any analysis to see if you actually need to do this?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

Comment: https://github.com/tchandy/octopus may be useful.